# How can I find $F(2,3)$. Linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $F:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ be a linear function such that $F (0, 1) = 7$, $F (1, 0) = 3$. Find $F (2, 3)$. 
I don't understand what does it mean "find $F(2,3)$". What I should do?
Give me a hint, please.

Comment: Given that $F$ is a linear function, your strategy should be to decompose $F(2,3)$ into some combination of $F(1,0)$ and $F(0,1)$, and then plug in the given values.

Comment: Since $F$ is linear, we have $F(ax,by)=aF(x,0)+bF(0,y)$ for scalars $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function $F$ is linear. This implies that 
$$F(2;3)=F(2;0)+F(0;3).$$
Using the property that $F(\alpha v)=\alpha F(v)$ for all $\alpha$ in your base field, we have
$$F(2;0)+F(0;3)=2F(1;0)+3F(0;1).$$
I leave you to finish up the proof.

Comment: I undersood! Thank you!

Comment: But what if I have coordinates without zero?  For example, I have F(1;1) and F(1;-1). How I can solve it?

Answer (score 2):

As F is linear  $F(2,3)=F(2,0)+F(0,3)=2F(1,0)+3F(0,1)=6+21=27$